# Should a REST Service Error Response Payload be Consistent with the Media Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, error-handling, mime-types

I have a REST service that supports various media types (MIME types) such as `application/xml`, `application/json`, `application/vnd.ms-excel`, `text/plain`. This service is consumed by browsers requests as well as HTTP clients in application code.

However, when consuming this REST service, my client code needs to handle errors in a consistent manner.  To do this, the error payload would have to be in consistent media type like JSON so it can be deserialized.

So my question is, am I breaking any RESTful best practices if I return an error payload which in inconsistent with the requested media type?  If not, what format should I use? JSON?

**Update**

To clarify, when I say error payload, I am referring to the body of a response which has a status other than 200 and which needs to contain error details.

Comment: I would return a json like `{code:XXX,message:"",result:{...} }` for all responses (of course setting http response accordingly, 200,401,404 etc.) as most common rest services do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, an error doesn't have to include a payload. It's perfectly reasonable to just return a status code like 401 with an empty response body. However, if you need to return payload, then the response for an error should be same as the expected type for success. In other words, if the client requested JSON, return JSON both on success and error. Likewise, if XML was requested, the error response should be in XML.

Comment: This makes sense in most cases; however, what if the requested media type is incompatible with the error details.  For example an Excel document (flat data) or an image?

Comment: If the type is binary, then there should be no response body on error. The point is that the client relies on the requested type being returned. Expecting it to shift from grabbing a binary to parsing JSON or something is unreasonable. Really, no api method should ever return binary anyways. If it's responsible for something like generating an Excel doc, it should save the result and return a response object that includes the location where the client can fetch the result, or even redirect automatically.